Method 'main()' does not have signature 'public static void main(String[])'. The program cannot be started while main has this problem
When trying to complete a task ("Create a Dog class containing two String type fields: name and says. In the method
main() create two Dog objects with different names (spot and scruffy) and messages.
Print the values of both fields for each of the objects") the project cannot be started.
the program itself:
public class Doges {

    String name;
    String says;

    public Doges(String name, String says) {
        this.name = name;
        this.says = says;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Doges spot = new Doges ( "Spot","My name Spot bro, u know?");
        Doges scruffy = new Doges ("Scruffy","Yeah, i know man, but im - Scruffy and im Dog");

        System.out.println(STR."\{spot.name}: \{spot.says}");
        System.out.println(STR."\{scruffy.name}: \{scruffy.says}");
    }
}

I tried swapping classes, but that wasn't the cause of the problem.

Your code seems correct, how are you running the code?

the program cannot be started, I try to do it with the keys (shift + f10), but it does not work

Well, if you're using IntelliJ IDEA, the issue might be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-339606

The language in which the program is written is Java. Syntax like "System.out.println(STR."{sort.name }: {pat.says}")" - this seems to be the new syntax of south, because I don't get an error saying that I'm using it incorrectly. On the other hand, there is a comment about the usual record. Apparently, the development environment dictates writing this way. I do not know how to add a tag to an existing question

Does moving the main function out of the dog class body help?

does not work, returns at error

You can click [edit] to edit anything about your question, including adding more context to the question. And apparently the STR. stuff is JEP-430, I'm starting to feel old ;-)

This works fine for me if I include jvm arguments,  --enable-preview --source 21 What is your development environment? I suspect you have the run misconfigured.

Try updating your copy of IntelliJ IDEA.

It seems you are trying to run another method. Take attention to the run configuration, or execute this method using the run button across the main method on the left side of the panel.  Another way - try this: File -> Invalidate Caches.. -> select all -> Invalidate and restart

Nothing helped. Maybe it's the way the code itself is built. I'll try to rebuild it. Thank you all so much for your help!
